# ASP.NET Core Web API : accept any route, any method, any verb

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to create a mock service that accepts any route, any HTTP verb, etc..

[GET or POST or Whatever] http://[ip]/anyaction

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: How? Do u have any example?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own middleware that simply replies all requests:

```
public class AcceptAllMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public AcceptAllMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {            
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("I accept anything and everything.");            
        await context.Response.CompleteAsync();
    }
}
```

Then remove everything from the middleware pipeline on the Startup class and add your middleware:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<AcceptAllMiddleware>();
}
```